# Is there a way to Cycle Start the Okuma OSP-300 programatically?

Tags: okuma

Is there a way to cycle start the CNC using the SDK? If I could programatically cyclestart the CNC that would save us some hardware rewiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no and I believe OEM will say no even to an engineering request for it because of safety. BUT you can cycle start then pause in code and wait for a common variable to change. With some creative use of User Task 3, you can call subroutines by common variable as well.

Comment: I agree with you, and expected the same thing. However, I'm told there are CNCs that allow you to cycle start with software commands. We currently do it via a signal from a PLC that emulates the button press on other CNCs, and that's what we will do here, not a huge hurdle, just one if I could do with software would save manpower over time.